# Get the approximate time of a point on a curve

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, curve

I'm working on an animation. The objective is simple: when the user clicks on a button, the bar grows or reduces the size to the option the user clicked on, and the option color is changed. But when the bar passes through another option (including what the user did not clicked), this option color is changed too.

The concept and the implementation is not complex, but I want to do something smooth and nice, and to do this, I need to use some curves. And right here is the problem.

When I animate the bar with a linear curve, the code run very nice and everything happens when it needs to happen. When the bar passes through an option, the color is changed in the exact time that the bar passes. But when I have a curve, this not happen. The color is changed before or after the bar passes.

When using the the Linear Curve: the bar passes and the color is changed in the correct moment.

[Curves.linear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihneV.gif)

When using the the Slow Middle Curve: the bar passes and the color is changed before or after.

[Curves.slowMiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlngY.gif)

The logic I'm using is: get the number of item the bar will go to and divide the duration time of the animation for the number of items the bar will pass. And then, I make a `Future.delayed` to animate the color change. For example: from 0 to 3. The bar will pass 3 items. 2 seconds divided by 3 items. The color of the items will be changed every 667 milliseconds.

So, if I can get the time when the curve touch some point, I can use this time to apply a delay and change the color in the exact time when the bar passes.
The question is: **Is there a way to get the approximate time of a point on the curve to apply a delay to change the color?**

**Important**: if someone know a way to create a logic that observes the width of the bar (AnimatedContainer) and use this width to change the color, this would be appreciate. I dont know how to create something like this.

Function that change the color of the button:

```
alteraCorItemStepper(int indiceItem){
  if(ultimoIndicePressionado < indiceItem){
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
      listaProdutos[indiceItem].corWidget = res.azul_claro;
      listaProdutos.refresh();
    });
    for(int i = 1; i < indiceItem; i++){
      int numb = i;
      int div = indiceItem - ultimoIndicePressionado;
      int time = (2000/div).round() * numb;
      int indexAlterar = ultimoIndicePressionado + i;
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: time), () {
        if(indexAlterar <= indiceItem){
          listaProdutos[indexAlterar].corWidget = res.azul_claro;
          listaProdutos.refresh();
        }
      });
    }
  }
  if(ultimoIndicePressionado > indiceItem){
    listaProdutos[ultimoIndicePressionado].corWidget = Colors.white;
    listaProdutos.refresh();
    for(int i = 1; i < ultimoIndicePressionado; i++){
      int numb = i;
      int div = ultimoIndicePressionado - indiceItem;
      int time = (2000/div).round() * numb;
      int indexAlterar = ultimoIndicePressionado - i;
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: time), () {
        if(indexAlterar > indiceItem){
          listaProdutos[indexAlterar].corWidget = Colors.white;
          listaProdutos.refresh();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Button Widget:

```
Obx(() =>
  GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){
      controller.valorAtualProgress.value = widget.valorProgress;
      controller.alteraCorItemStepper(widget.indiceItem);
      controller.ultimoIndicePressionado = widget.indiceItem;
    },
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 4,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
      ),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
        height: largura_total/28,
        width: largura_total/28,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: controller.listaProdutos[widget.indiceItem].corWidget,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
        ),
        child: Center(
            child: Obx(() =>
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  controller.listaProdutos[widget.indiceItem].corWidget == res.azul_claro
                    ? controller.listaProdutos[widget.indiceItem].icone_branco
                    : controller.listaProdutos[widget.indiceItem].icone_azul_claro,
                  height: (largura_total/28)*0.5,
                  width: (largura_total/28)*0.5,
                )
            )
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And here is the Complete Layout:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
                height: largura_total/28,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    height: (largura_total/28)/3,
                    width: largura - 32,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Obx(() =>
                Container(
                    height: largura_total/28,
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: AnimatedContainer(
                          height: (largura_total/28)/3,
                          width: (largura - 32) * controller.valorAtualProgress.value,
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                          curve: Curves.slowMiddle,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: res.azul_claro,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                          ),
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for(int i = 0; i < controller.listaProdutos.length; i++)
              WidgetItemStepperConsultiva(i, (1/5) * i)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: @pskink I think this could help. But I don't understand what is happening with the `..._curves.map((r)`. Can you please maybe explain basically what is happening on that code?

Comment: this is so called "spread operator", for more check https://dart.dev/language/collections#spread-operators